# how to fill zeros matrix with ones based on a list of values

Tags: python, numpy

I have k = [3, 2, 0, 1] and A array filled with zeros. I want to fill A with ones such that each row sums up to a value in k

```
k = [3, 2, 0, 1]
A = np.zeros((n, n), dtype=int)
for i in k:
   A = np.random.randint(2, size=i)
```

the expected output:

```
([[1., 0., 1., 1.],
     [0., 1., 1., 0.],
     [1., 0., 1., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

I appreciate it

Comment: `Row1sum = 3, Row2sum = 2, Row3sum=2, Row4sum=0`, yet `k = [3,2,0,1]`. So what you are saying is that as long as it adds up to `3 OR 2 OR 1 OR 0` it is OK ???

Comment: `np.random.default_rng().permuted(np.arange(n) < np.array(k)[:,None], axis=1).astype(int)`, IIUC. The expected array isn't random, only the permutation is random.

Answer (score 0):

You may use numpy.random.choice

[numpy.random.choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

> Generates a random sample from a given 1-D array

```
import numpy as np

k = [3, 2, 0, 1]
n = 4
A = np.zeros((n, n), dtype=int)

for idx, row_sum in enumerate(k):
    x = np.random.choice(n, row_sum, replace=False)
    A[idx, x] = 1

print(A)
```

output will be like

```
[[1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can fill the rows by assigning the values like this.

```
A[i, : k[i]] = 1
```

Or

```
A[i, np.random.choice(n, k[i], replace=False)] = 1 # Fill the row with ones in random positions
```

So the working example should look like this:

```
import numpy as np

k = [3, 2, 0, 1]
n = len(k)
A = np.zeros((n, n), dtype=int)

for i in range(n):
    A[i, np.random.choice(n, k[i], replace=False)] = 1 # ones in random positions
```

The output of `A`

```
[[1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1]]
```